# How To Connect Redux To React Functional Component

Tags: reactjs, redux

The error I'm getting is "TypeError: Cannot set property 'props' of undefined".

What I was trying to do is to connect redux to my functional (stateless) component.
I guess that I wrote it wrong, but I can't figure out how to write it correctly and make it work.

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'


const Logger = (props) => {
    console.log(props.event);

    let logger = []

    if(localStorage.getItem("logger")){
      logger = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("logger"))
    }

    let d = new Date();
    let h = d.getHours();
    let m = d.getMinutes();
    let s = d.getSeconds();
    let time = (h + ":" + m + ":" + s)

    logger.push(
      {
        time: time,
        event: props.event
      }
    )

    localStorage.setItem("logger", JSON.stringify(logger))
    props.logger(logger)
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) =>{
  return{
    logger: (value) => {
      dispatch({
        type: 'LOGGER',
        payload: value
      })
    }
  }
} 

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Logger)
```

Comment: Which line are you getting this error?

Comment: React/node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:394

Comment: Are you not returning anything from the component?

Comment: nope, for this specific component, I don't need to

Comment: you have to return jsx or null and render it somewhere for it to be a component per se

Comment: I import it to a different component and call it there, even if I return "null" or div it doesn't work